# Disable onmouseover event when width screen matches media queries

Tags: javascript, media-queries, onmouseover

I am using an onMouseover event inside an "a" html tag.

```
<a href="#" onMouseover="ddrivetip('text')"; onMouseout="hideddrivetip()">
```

In my project I also use media queries in the CSS.

```
@media screen and (min-width: 241px) and (max-width: 320px){
    /*CSS code here*/
}
```

My question is, how can I disable the onMouseover when the width of the screen matches one of the media queries?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure if you can disable mouseover using media tag. But I am sure you can use jquery / javascript to disable it.

Comment: In those mouse event functions, check for something that is defined in your media query. For example, let say your media query has an element display set to none. You can use js to check and see if that element's display is none or not and gate the function's functionality to execute or not

Comment: check window.matchMedia(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.matchMedia and implement it into your ddrivetip function.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still useful. Writing an answer for the people that should pass by here, following @SamuliHakoniemi comment.

The `window.matchMedia()` method returns a new `MediaQueryList` object that can be used to determine if the document matches the given media query string. Its `matches` property will be true if the document meets the media query's requirements.

For example, you can build a simple function to programmatically determine if a *(min-width: 1100px)* media query string is matched:

```
function ismatching() {
  let mql = window.matchMedia('(min-width: 1100px)');
  return mql.matches;
}
```

Then call this function before your code, to check if the width of the screen matches the media query.

If you need to be aware of changes to the evaluated result of the query on an ongoing basis, it's more efficient to register a listener: please see [Testing media queries programmatically](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Testing_media_queries) for a complete example.

Reference: [Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)